# Crystal Reports Parameter/Drill Down Issue

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm currently using CR 2008 for design and running my reports in InfoView. I have a fairly standard report with about 6 groupings and 2 details sections. The groupings are all hierarchichal and can be drilled into. The report contains 5 parameters that the user has access to edit in Infoview.

My problem occurs only when users change any parameter on the report and then attempt to drill down in the report. The result always ends up that the drill down will display the very first Group, with drill down, in the report rather than the one they selected to drill into. If a user enters the report and drills into any group without changing the parameters, everything works as expected.

Has anyone ever seen this kind of behavior or know of a reason that this might be happening? Please help.

Thank You,

Patrick Johnson

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a reach, but when you change the parameters, are you refreshing the data (ie. don't use the saved data that was pulled originally). I believe something may be going wrong because of that.

Always, always, always choose to refresh your data.